# Register for all file types (CFBundleDocumentTypes)

Tags: iphone, uidocumentinteraction

Programs like Drop Box, or Airsharing don't handle or edit documents but store them.  In this case it would seem that they have to register as being a valid choice for any type of file.  Is there a way to register your application as a handler for all files? '.*' ?  Or is the only solution to register for any type of file that you can think of?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Registering for the public.data type accepts EVERYTHING. If you want specific actions for certain types of files you will need to check when it gets passed to your app. See this apple doc for the hierarchy: [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE)

Edit for clarification: public.data allows for your app to accept any kind of data type. (image/text/etc..)..the very base UTI is public.item (includes public.data and public.content and public.archive). As i'm not sure what you are really trying to do, it could be that you want the other stuff as well.